# How can i rewrite this responsive html5 video header to smaller height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, header

I really like this hero responsive video background in div element. However this is really big on full size window. The 100% width is absolutely ok, but i need only 50%-30% height to my site. When i modified the height in the css, a large empty area created between the video and the content. Seems like i still need to modify something, can you help me pls?

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/8R7Xx/">Link</a>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: added the jsfiddle link

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, the problem isn't a ratio thing after all. Just go `*0.30` for 30% on the height in javascript. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need only 50%-30% height to my site

Just multiple height in the javascript with 0.45 to get 45%

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/n8zLct0z/embedded/result/)

```
var unitHeight = (parseInt(height)*0.45) + 'px';
```

Comment: any chance i can modify the focus point on the video? As you can see live because of the modified height i only see the bottom of the video: http://perenyi.eu/projekt/eteleink.html      Here is the video, i would like to focus on the pizza: http://perenyi.eu/projekt/videoplayback.mp4

Comment: You could try out `margin-top:-100px;` while you add 100px to the height of the video in javascript. `var unitHeight = ((parseInt(height)*0.45)+100) + 'px'; $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight); $('.homepage-hero-module').css('margin-top','-100px');`

Comment: Thank you,undortunately the video remains the same: http://jsfiddle.net/n8zLct0z/1/   Maybe i need to find a more "responsive" video